# Fill Chart.js with specific JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Currently i'm trying to learn Javascript, however I can't seem to get this problem fixed:

I have a Json file which is filled with data. I want the specific arrays of the first month August (Reports, Average, Global) and insert them (via a variable) into my chart. So I get a chart with:

August

- Reports: 7
- Average: 25
- Global: 20

June ... ect.

**Any help or tips are welcome!!**

> JSON Data

```
[{
    "month": "August",
    "reports": 7,
    "average": 25,
    "global": 20,
    "percentage": 14
}, {
    "month": "July",
    "reports": 22,
    "average": 25,
    "global": 20,
    "percentage": 44
}, {
    "month": "June",
    "reports": 12,
    "average": 25,
    "global": 20,
    "percentage": 24
}]
```

> JS Code

```
window.onload = function() {

    var reports = [];

    $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
        reports = data;
    });


    var repaug = 7;
    var avg = 25;
    var global = 20;

    var ctx = document.getElementById("Chart1");
    var Chart1 = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ["Reports", "Average PSN", "Global Average"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of reports',
                data: [repaug, global, avg],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {}
    })
}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

Inside of [`datasets`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/?h=datasets) you could add an array so first you need to loop for your response.

You could use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method for array.

**DEMO**

```js
let arrayData =[{"month":"August","reports":7,"average":25,"global":20,"percentage":14},{"month":"July","reports":22,"average":25,"global":20,"percentage":44},{"month":"June","reports":12,"average":25,"global":20,"percentage":24}],
    datasets = arrayData.map(item => {
        return {
            label: `${item.month}`,
            data: [item.reports, item.average, item.global],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }
    }),
    ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["Reports", "Average PSN", "Global Average"],
        datasets: datasets
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
        },
        animation: {
            animateScale: true,
            animateRotate: true
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(item, data) {
                    let datasets = data.datasets,
                        dIndex = item.datasetIndex,
                        index = item.index;
                  
                    return `${datasets[dIndex].label} : ${data.labels[index]} : ${datasets[dIndex].data[index]}`;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hi is it possible to change it to bar chart?

Comment: @Suvin94 Could you pls let me know what you need in bar chart ?

Comment: I am trying to make a same concept with stacked chart from mysql database. Is it possible? The array(from database) of labels which shows different colours and value array from database.

Comment: I still can't find a good tutorial for stacked chart with laravel mysql database

Comment: Yes you can. Please this working [codepen](https://codepen.io/narendrajadhav/pen/abzpWam). This will help you more to configure stacked chart.

Comment: Hi sir, can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59401776/chart-js-how-to-push-a-collection-of-array-into-dataset

Comment: @Suvin94 Please check I have updated the [codepen](https://codepen.io/narendrajadhav/pen/abzpWam).