# Chart.js - How to push a collection of array into dataset

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js, chart.js2

I have been trying many ways to push the collection of array into the dataset.
Anyone can help me to push an array into stacked chart based on the codepen below?

Here's the example

[Codepen stacked bar](https://codepen.io/narendrajadhav/pen/abzpWam)

Javascript

```
const getData = ()=>new Array(7).fill('').map(v=>randomScalingFactor());

var barChartData = {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Dataset 1',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                data: getData()
            }, {
                label: 'Dataset 2',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                data: getData()
            }, {
                label: 'Dataset 3',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.green,
                data: getData()
            }]

        };
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartData,
                options: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked'
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            stacked: true
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });

        document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
            barChartData.datasets.forEach(dataset=>{
                dataset.data = getData();
            });
            window.myBar.update();
        });
```

Here's the data for arrays

[image]

The issues should be the dataset with different colors and total should be the value for Y axis and there should be another collection of array date for X axis and the colors for the dataset should be different. The data for issues and total will be retrieved from Mysql database.

I am using laravel and the table above was achieved using foreach loop.

Comment: Please check I have updated the [codepen](https://codepen.io/narendrajadhav/pen/abzpWam). And could you please paste here your data array instead of image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should provide more information. What have you tried, what failed...
Don't expect people do your job, wasting their time so you can nap for an hour. StackOverflow is for specific questions and not for letting others do somebody else's work. And getting data for `chart.js` is something trivial you can find in any other post about `chart.js`.

Enough ranting, just letting you know you shouldn't expect answers in the future for questions like that.

1. The code you posted in your question is quite different to the one from the codepen link, but this can be due to Narendra Jadhav's 'update'. But if confused me enough so I don't know what you want.
2. You didn't stated if you want to update our data so I didn't implemented updating.
3. Don't know the use case of this random `randomizeData()` does, especially with the fixed length of 7. I changed it but as I don't know the reason it may be different to your use case.
4. I don't know the data format you get from MySQL so I used a possible format. Same as above, could be different to what you want.
5. Please use an newer version of `chart.js` and not a year old version. There are no breaking changes, only improvements. Just updating the version eliminated a few bugs, e.g. the strange space between the yAxis and the chart.

Complete code ([same as JSBin](https://jsbin.com/daxogutelo/1/edit?js,output)):

```
var initialData = [
  {
    'Barcode Sticker Problem':1,
    'Extra':1,
    'Labelling Problem':2,
    'Stock Accuracy':1,
    'Wrong Quality':1
  },{
    'Barcode Sticker Problem':1,
    'Extra':1,
    'Labelling Problem':2,
    'Stock Accuracy':1,
    'Wrong Quality':3
  },
  {
    'Barcode Sticker Problem':2,
    'Extra':2,
    'Labelling Problem':1,
    'Stock Accuracy':2,
    'Wrong Quality':3
  }
]

const colors = [
  'red',
  'blue',
  'green'
]

var barChartData = {
  labels: Object.keys(initialData[0]),
  datasets: []
};

for (var i = 0; i < initialData.length; i++) {
  barChartData.datasets.push(
    {
      label: 'Dataset ' + (i+1),
      backgroundColor: colors[i % colors.length],
      data: Object.values(initialData[i])
    }
  )
}

var barChartOptions = {
  title: {
    display: false,
    text: 'Chart.js Stacked Bar Chart'
  },
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false
  },
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      ticks: {
        precision: 0
      }
    }]
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: barChartData,
  options: barChartOptions
});

document.getElementById('randomizeData').addEventListener('click', function() {
  barChartData.datasets.forEach(dataset=>{
    var newData = []
    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
      newData.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1)
    }
    dataset.data = newData
  });
  window.myBar.update();
});
```

Comment: Hey Thank you for the great example! actually i have solved the issues few days ago but i will try to improve my charts with your example. Thanks Again!